# Primeng dropdown with 2 different options to filter table data

Tags: html, angular, frontend, primeng

I have the next p-dropdown

```
<p-dropdown inputId="type1" [options]="type" placeholder="Role"
            #statusDropdown (onChange)="dt.filter(statusDropdown.value, 'role', 'equals')">
            </p-dropdown>
```

I have a p-table (#dt) where **I display 4 diffrent user types named 'role': Applicant, recruiter, evaluator and administrator.**

What I need is to filter the users with just 2 options in the dropdown:

- Applicant: Get just Applicants users
- Administrative: Get Recruiter, Evaluators and Administrators (in other words get all users except Applicants)

These are my options:

```
type: string[] = ['Applicant', 'Administrative'];
```

As you can see I have an onChange event that obviously works when the dropdown Applicant option is selected, but when Administrative is it doesn't because there is no role named 'Administrative'. So I don't know which is the best way to solve this problem. Thanks.

#### Edit

This are my users:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Administrador",
        "username": "Admin",
        "email": "test@qacg.com",
        "active": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "expirationDate": "2022-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
        "role": "Administrator"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Sttefany Klee",
        "username": "sttefany.klee",
        "email": "test@qacg.com",
        "active": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "expirationDate": "2022-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
        "role": "Evaluator"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Mario Olvera",
        "username": "mario.olvera",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "active": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "expirationDate": "2022-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
        "role": "Recruiter"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Ricardo Ruiz",
        "username": "ricardodars",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "active": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "expirationDate": "2022-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
        "role": "Applicant"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Dan Olvera",
        "username": "dantegalante",
        "email": "test@hotmail.com",
        "active": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "expirationDate": "2022-04-23T18:25:43.511Z",
        "role": "Applicant"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can you also paste you `dt.filter` function + a sample of your data the filtering is performed on?

Comment: `dt.filter` is the one in the `(onChange)` event but it was just an idea because it is not the solution. Data is now in the ask body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the filter also has `in`. I'd try the following:

```
<p-dropdown inputId="type1" [options]="type" placeholder="Role" #statusDropdown 
  (onChange)="statusDropdown.value === 'Applicant' ? dt.filter(statusDropdown.value, 'role', 'equals') : dt.filter(['Recruiter', 'Evaluators', 'Administrators'], 'role', 'in')"
></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: This works for a while but, I added to my p-dropdwon `[showClear]="true"` but when is empty applies the option 2, how could I add an empty condition?